# What effect causes this Pattern?

Tags: signal-analysis, sound, wave, acoustics, sweep

I've conducted a measurement of underwater noise in a laboratory experiment.
Therefore i am using a sweep signal.

Sometimes -I guess when the signal is much more louder- I get this fascinating repeating and kind of symmetric pattern when I analyse the signal. Can someone name the *physical phenomena* involved which are causing this?

The picture below shows the response without Pattern:

[image: Signal without repeating Pattern]

Response with repeating Pattern:

[image: Signal with repeating Pattern]

The only difference I can find is that the recorded response is much louder. I am still clueless and fascinated which physical phenomena might be the cause of the

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is that this is clipping or some other form of non-linear distortion. If you clip a sine wave you end up with mostly odd harmonics. You have some even ones in here too, but they are a lot weaker.

So chances are: something in your signal chain is overdrive: could be the DAC, the power amp, the transducer itself (quite likely), the microphone, the pre-amp, the ADC, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Can you think of any other reason this occurs? 
Yes it is a sine sweep roughly starting at 10 Hz up to 700 Hz.
Can you please try to explain how clipping exactly results in this pattern?

Comment: @hoaratius, this is well documented in the Exponential Sine Sweep (ESS) method. You can find some information about it in the following links: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86924/40198, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87031/40198, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41700/40198. You can also search for information about the method online. A Google search for the method will give enough information (the researcher who introduced it is Angelo Farina, in case this helps).

Comment: Okay. Thank you both for your help. Appreciate it a lot. And thank you both for taking time and answering my question @ZaellixA